# Customer name is not showing on paypal recurring payments

Tags: paypal

I create a recurring payment in PayPal using Lionite Paypal API class. I pass 'name' parameter to the class, but no customer name is showing on paypal statement when I receive the payment. Other parameters are showing as expected. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Need to see the actual API request the class is generating.  Maybe it's not handling the 'name' parameter correctly.

Comment: @AndrewAngell  
`Formatted Request: Array  
(  
    [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => qwe rty  
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-12-26T15:13:58-08:00  
    [DESC] => Monthly subscription  
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month  
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
    [AMT] => 9.99
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => Visa
    [ACCT] => **************4242
    [CVV2] => REDACTED
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [EMAIL] => zd@test.com
    [EXPDATE] => REDACTED
    [STREET] => qwer 34
    [CITY] => ert
    [STATE] => re
    [ZIP] => 12343
    [COUNTRYCODE] => qwe
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add parameters 'FIRSTNAME' and 'LASTNAME' to API call.

Comment: In Lionite Paypal API module, 'name' parameter passed to API class is transformed to 'SUBSCRIBERNAME' which is passed to Paypal API.
To specify subscriber's name that appears on statements, we also have to pass 'FIRSTNAME' and/or 'LASTNAME' parameter (at least one of them). To do this, we have to modify Lionite's class to add translation of parameters to `$_recurringPaymentsOptions`, and then pass the value to the class.

Comment: For future projects you may be interested in taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  I don't have little problems like that within it.  :)